# Linking tables with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables;
memberID, membership, person

I need firstname lastname from 'membership' and
MemberID and PersonID from 'memberID'
The following gives me a list of names.

```
   SELECT 
   CONCAT(P.FirstName, ' ', P.LastName) as FullName
   FROM `membership` M
   INNER JOIN `memberID` MI ON M.`MembershipID` = MI.`MembershipID`
   INNER JOIN `person` P ON MI.`PersonID` = P.`PersonID`
   AND P.`IsActive` =1
```

The following fails, how do I add the PersonID and MembershipID columns, .
I believe I require another INNER JOIN but I don't know how to construct it.

```
   SELECT
   CONCAT(P.FirstName, ' ', P.LastName) as FullName
   FROM `membership` M
   MI.'membershipID' MI.'PersonID' FROM  'membershipID' MI
   INNER JOIN `memberID` MI ON M.`MembershipID` = MI.`MembershipID`

   INNER JOIN `person` P ON MI.`PersonID` = P.`PersonID`
   AND P.`IsActive` =1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably those columns are already in the tables being referenced:

```
SELECT CONCAT(P.FirstName, ' ', P.LastName) as FullName,
       MI.PersonID, M.`MembershipID`
FROM `membership` M INNER JOIN
     `memberID` MI
     ON M.`MembershipID` = MI.`MembershipID` INNER JOIN
     `person` P
     ON MI.`PersonID` = P.`PersonID` AND P.`IsActive` = 1;
```

You don't need additional joins, just additional columns in the `select`.

Comment: This one did it.. Thanks